# Is the problem of "finding the output given the algorithm halts" not computable?

Tags: turing-machines, computability

For simplicity, let's assume all Turing machines print 0 or 1 on the tape. Consider an algorithm $A$, which, given any Turing machine $T$ as the input, outputs $x\in \{0,1\}$, satisfying the condition that if $T$ halts, then the last symbol printed by $T$ is $x.$
When $T$ does not halt, it does not matter what the output of $A$ is.

Is it the case that algorithm $A$ does not exist (and thus the problem is undecidable)?

Comment: You're basically asking about diagonally non-recursive functions (specifically $\mathsf{DNR}_2$ functions). These are indeed non-computable, although they can be much simpler than the halting problem $\emptyset'$ itself - namely, they can be *low* (a function $A$ is low iff [$A'\equiv_T0'$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_jump)).

Answer (score 1):

The assumption that the output is one bit does not actually simplify matters - the proof is easier for machines that can output strings.

Let $U_M$ be the machine which simulates the machine $M$ and outputs the protocol of computation of $M$ (the sequence of successive configurations of $M$ until it halts). If $M$ does not halt, then $U_M$ also does not halt. The encoding of $U_M$ can be computed from the encoding of $M$.

Now we can solve the halting problem using the algorithm $A$: given $M$, construct $U_M$, run $A$ on $U_M$, and check that the result is indeed the protocol of computation of $M$. If it is the protocol, then $M$ halts, and if not, then $M$ does not halt.

Your version reduces to this one by asking for the protocol bits separately.

UPD: I realized there is an easier construction which uses the diagonal method directly. Suppose $A$ exists. Let $Q_M$ be the machine which runs $M$ giving it $M$ as an input. Let $B$ be the machine which takes a Turing machine $M$, constructs $Q_M$, runs $A$ on the machine $Q_M$, and returns the negation of the result obtained by $A$.

Formally, if $[M]$ denotes the encoding of $M$, then by definition of $A$ we have $A([M]) = M()$ if $M() \in \{0, 1\}$, and $A([M]) \in \{0,1\}$ if $M() = \bot$. We defined $Q_M() = M([M])$ and $B([M]) = \neg A([Q_M])$.

Note that $B([M]) = \neg A([Q_M])$ is always defined, and we get a contradiction $B([B]) = \neg A([Q_B]) = \neg Q_B() = \neg B([B])$.

Comment: Why M must halt when the protocol matches?

Comment: Because a finite protocol only exists if $M$ halts.

Comment: I updated the answer with a simpler construction

Comment: Thank you. Let me have a look.

Comment: Your new argument does work. But why can't A print a finite protocol anyway even if M does not halt?

Comment: Because we can check the protocol again and see that it is incomplete.

Comment: I mean $A$ can print a complete protocol anyway even if $M$ does not halt.

Comment: If $M$ does not halt, then the complete protocol printed by $A$ will diverge from the actual computation of $A$ at some point, because the protocol is finite and the actual computation is infinite.